# Toggle button with enabled disabled / change json value angular

Tags: json, angular, toggle

I want to create a toggle button who change the json boolean value in the Dom. I want to disable or enable a div

```js
check: boolean = true;
  
  
  checkStatus(status) {
    if(status) {
      this.check = false;
    } else {
      this.check = true;
    }
    console.log(status);
  }
```

```html
{
        id: 1,
        name: 'PV Panels',
        currentP: '100 kW',
        setpp: '100 kW',
        currentq: '2 kVar',
        setq: '2 kVar',
        required: true

    },
    
    
    HTML
    
      <label>
      <td ><input [ngModel]="test" [checked]="check" type="checkbox" (change) = "checkStatus(status)"></td>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5xyuaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

TS file

```
check: boolean = false;

  checkStatus() {
    this.check = !this.check;
    this.json.required = this.check;
  }

  json = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'PV Panels',
        currentP: '100 kW',
        setpp: '100 kW',
        currentq: '2 kVar',
        setq: '2 kVar',
        required: this.check
  }
```

HTML file

```
<label>
  <td >
    <input [checked]="this.check"       
    type="checkbox" (change) = "this.checkStatus()">
  </td>
</label>

<div *ngIf="check">
  DIV TO SHOW OR HIDE
</div>

{{ this.json | json }}
```

Comment: Thanks Works Fine !